# Fragment, two class for smartphone and tablet?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

i am developing an app for tablet and smartphone.

My question is if i need other class and duplicate code when im using phone or tablet. This is my code..

**large_land/main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment class="com.example.example.FragmentMenu"
    android:id="@+id/FragmentMenu"
    android:layout_weight="30"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_weight="70"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**layout/main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    class="com.example.example.FragmentMenu"
    android:id="@+id/FragmentMenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**main.java**

```
public class main extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
private boolean isTablet;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 

    isTablet = findViewById(R.id.content_frame) != null;
    if(isTablet) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.content_frame,  new FragmentInicio());
        ft.commit();
    } 



    final FragmentMenu frgMenu =(FragmentMenu)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.FragmentMenu); 
    frgMenu.setListMenuListener(new MenuListListener() {

        @Override
        public void onListMenuSeleccionado(Menu_List c) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(c.getID()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

            // HERE IS MY PROBLEM.. WHEN THE DEVICE IS A TABLET THE APP 
            // OPEN 'FRAGMENTINICIO' OR 'FRAGMENTBLOG', 
            // BUT WHEN THE DEVICE IS A MOBILE. DO I NEED TO CREATE ANOTHER CLASS AND DUPLICATE CODE?


            if(isTablet) {
                FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                switch (c.getID()) {
                case 0:
                    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE);
                    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new FragmentInicio());
                    ft.commit();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new FragmentBlog());
                    ft.commit();
                    break;
                } 
            } else {
                Intent i;
                switch (c.getID()) { 
                case 0:
                    i = new Intent(main.this, InicioActivity.class); 
                    startActivity(i);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    i = new Intent(main.this, BlogActivity.class); 
                    startActivity(i);
                    break;
                }  
            }
        }
    }); 
}  
}
```

sorry for my English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only your View based classes should be duplicated to adapt to screen sizes.

For the data you should keep them as a separate class and follow the MVC pattern where the the view should not have any relation to data, your controller/common dataSource adapter/class should handle the code between data and view functioning.

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need two classes. If all the views in one layout file are present in the other layout(s) too, you don't have to do any special handling. However, if the views are different and/or their IDs don't match, you will have to do detection inside the classes and assign values accordingly.

One thing that you have to handle is the state of your views. Handle the lifecycle properly in order to handle rotation through `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()`

That's it!